# Expanding all collapsible sections on a web page

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am interested in finding out if there is a way to expand all the collapsible sections on a webpage simultaneously. A relevant section on the webpage I am looking at looks like this:

```html
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="..;">
        <div style="..">
            <span id=".." style="display:inline;"><br />
                <div style="display:inline"> ... 
                </div>
            </span>
            <span id="toHide1234" style="display:none;"><br />
                <div style="display:inline">
                    <p>.....</p>
                </div>
            </span>
            <a id="expcoll1234" href="JavaScript:expandcollapse('expcoll1234',1234)">
                expand
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

As seen above, by clicking on `expand` link, this section would expand. Trouble is, there are hundreds of such `expand` links on the webpage I am interested in, and there are many such web pages I want to do this for.

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated. I need a really simple way to do this, as I am not very well versed with web programming. Just know very elementary HTML.

Comment: So you want to use this on a website that isn’t under your control? Then you are limited in your possibilities to get your own JavaScript code inserted into that in the first place. It could perhaps work from the browser console or a “bookmarklet”, if the target site does not prevent that via CSP.

Comment: @CBroe You posted a comment earlier that I could simply 'disable the style elements' on the webpage. I notice that you have deleted your comment. Actually, I did just that and it solved my problem. Since this is exactly the kind of simple solution I was looking for, I would request that if you could post your deleted comment as an answer, I will accept it. PS: I used https://superuser.com/questions/447269/is-there-any-way-to-view-a-webpage-without-styles-in-chrome as a reference and used uMatrix extension on Google Chrome to disable CSS.

Comment: Sure, happy to :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to use this on a website that isn’t under your control? Then you are limited in your possibilities to get your own JavaScript code inserted into that in the first place. It could perhaps work from the browser console or a “bookmarklet”, if the target site does not prevent that via CSP.

If just getting at the “raw data” present in the HTML is the objective here, then your best bet is probably to disable styling in your browser completely - that overrides inline stuff like `style="display:none;"` as well, so that everything should be visible right from the start.

---

As you said in comments, https://superuser.com/questions/447269/is-there-any-way-to-view-a-webpage-without-styles-in-chrome led to [uMatrix browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/umatrix/ogfcmafjalglgifnmanfmnieipoejdcf), so if that works for your purposes - perfect ;-)

Comment: Yes, I simply just used the uMatrix extension to disable all CSS on the web pages I was interested in, and that caused all the relevant sections of the web pages to expand all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your hidden sections have ids of format `"toHide" + some numbers` you can find all the `<span>` elements on the page and filter them by id and change `display` style:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('span'))
     .filter(span => span.id.startsWith('toHide'))
     .forEach(span => { span.style.display = ''; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to do this.

First, you would probably want to give every `div` that expands an “expand” class or something, as welll as a class like “collapsed” that sets the height of the element to 0 (or however you are collapsing the element.)

```
<div class=“expand collapsed …”>
…
</div>
<div class=“expand collapsed…”>
…
</div>
```

You can then select all those `<div>`s simultaneously and remove the collapsed class like so:

```
$(‘.expand’).removeClass(‘collapsed’);
```

You can stick that line in a function and call the function on a button press by setting the button’s `onClick` Attribute to the name of the function.

Another approach is to use a library like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com)—Bootstrap has a lovely collapse mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where I wanted to expand all of the abstract sections on Arxiv automatically. Using the Chrome dev console I found this worked exactly like I wanted:

```
('.abstract-full').css('display','inline')
```

Since the "abstract-full" class had display: none.